# How can I assure that TikZ figures are displayed correctly in all PDF programs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

The MWE below generates TikZ drawings of an electric arc furnace and a ladle furnace, filled with custom patterns. In TeXstudio, they look just how I want them to – correct line thickness and the patterns filling out the shapes completely:
[image: TeXstudio]

However, when I view the same PDF in various other programs, their appearance is off at best and the overlay of pattern lines causes some ugly artefacts. I'd love to hear some suggestions on how I can guarantee my TikZpictures to be displayed correctly or at least consistently, maybe through some code adaptions.

### Foxit PDF Reader:

No difference in line thickness, patterns don't fill out shapes completely.

[image: Foxit PDF Reader]

### Mozilla Firefox:

Somewhat correct line thickness, but one shape isn't filled with the pattern at all.

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

### Microsoft Edge:

Also somewhat correct line thickness, but one shape isn't filled completely.

[image: Microsoft Edge]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shadings,patterns,intersections}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{% customization of pattern 
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=5pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=5pt
}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north west hatch}% name
{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
{\pgfqpoint{-\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,rounded corners=0.2mm] 
    \draw[pattern=north east hatch, hatch distance=2mm, hatch thickness=0.05mm] (0,0) coordinate(startpunkt1) --++(15mm,0) --++(0,8mm) .. controls ++(10mm,6mm) and ++(-10mm,0) .. ++(31mm,7mm) coordinate(mitteoben).. controls ++(10mm,0) and ++(-10mm,6mm) .. ++(31mm,-7mm) --++(0,-8mm)  coordinate(schlackeobenR) --++(-5mm,0) coordinate(schlackeobenL) --++(0,6mm) .. controls ++(-10mm,5mm) and ++(5mm,0) .. ++(-26mm,5mm) .. controls ++(-5mm,0) and ++(10mm,5mm) .. ++(-26mm,-5mm) --++(0mm,-9mm) --++(-20mm,0) coordinate(abstichoben)-- cycle;
    \draw[pattern=north east hatch, hatch distance=2mm, hatch thickness=0.05mm] (startpunkt1) ++(0,-8mm) coordinate(abstichunten) .. controls ++(25mm,-10mm) and ++(-20mm,0mm) .. ++(45mm,-14mm) coordinate(mitteunten) .. controls ++(20mm,0mm) and ++(-2mm,-1mm) .. ++(27mm,8mm) --++(0,6mm) coordinate(schlackeuntenL) --++(5mm,0) coordinate(schlackeuntenR) --++(0,-8mm) .. controls ++(-10mm,-8mm) and ++(10mm,0) .. ++(-31mm,-11mm) .. controls ++(-16mm,0) and ++(25mm,-12mm) .. ++(-46mm,17mm) -- cycle;
    \draw[rounded corners=0mm] (schlackeobenL) -- (schlackeuntenL) -- (schlackeuntenR) -- (schlackeobenR) -- cycle;
    \draw[rounded corners=0mm] (abstichoben)++(0,1mm) --++(0,-7mm);

    \foreach\i in {-10,0,10}{%
        \draw[fill=white] (mitteoben)++(-2mm,10mm)++(\i mm,0) rectangle ++(4mm,-33mm);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,rounded corners=0.2mm] 
    \draw[name path=pfanne,pattern=north east hatch, hatch distance=2mm, hatch thickness=0.05mm] (0,0) coordinate(startpunkt1) --++(18mm,0) --++(6mm,46mm) coordinate (obenrechts) --++(-3mm,0) --++(-5.6mm,{-46mm/6*5.6}) coordinate (eckeuntenrechts) --(startpunkt1 |-,|- eckeuntenrechts) 
    (startpunkt1) --++(-18mm,0) --++(-6mm,46mm) coordinate (obenlinks) --++(3mm,0) --++(5.6mm,{-46mm/6*5.6}) coordinate (eckeuntenlinks) --(startpunkt1 |-,|- eckeuntenlinks);
    \draw[pattern=north west hatch, hatch distance=2mm, hatch thickness=0.05mm] (obenlinks) ++(0,1.7mm) coordinate(startpunkt2) --++(0,1.5mm) --++(5mm,0) --++(9mm,3mm) coordinate(deckellinksoben) --(startpunkt1 |-,|- deckellinksoben) --++(0,-3mm) coordinate (deckelrechtsunten) -- (deckellinksoben |-,|- deckelrechtsunten) --++(-9mm,-3mm) --++(-5mm,0) --(startpunkt2)
    (obenrechts) ++(0,1.7mm) coordinate(startpunkt3) --++(0,1.5mm) --++(-5mm,0) --++(-9mm,3mm) coordinate(deckelrechtsoben) --(startpunkt1 |-,|- deckelrechtsoben) --++(0,-3mm) coordinate (deckelrechtsunten2) -- (deckelrechtsoben |-,|- deckelrechtsunten2) --++(9mm,-3mm) --++(5mm,0) --(startpunkt3);
    \path[name path=auxobenlinks] (startpunkt1) ++(-30mm,37mm) --++(20mm,0);
    \path[name path=auxobenrechts] (startpunkt1) ++(30mm,37mm) --++(-20mm,0);
    \path[name path=auxuntenlinks] (startpunkt1) ++(-30mm,34mm) --++(20mm,0);
    \path[name path=auxuntenrechts] (startpunkt1) ++(30mm,34mm) --++(-20mm,0);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=auxobenlinks and pfanne,by=collideobenlinks}];
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=auxobenrechts and pfanne,by=collideobenrechts}];
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=auxuntenlinks and pfanne,by=collideuntenlinks}];
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=auxuntenrechts and pfanne,by=collideuntenrechts}];
    \draw (collideobenlinks) --++(-4mm,0) coordinate (auxlinks);
    \draw (collideuntenlinks) -- (auxlinks |-,|- collideuntenlinks);
    \draw (collideobenrechts) --++(4mm,0) coordinate (auxrechts);
    \draw (collideuntenrechts) -- (auxrechts |-,|- collideuntenrechts);
    \draw (auxlinks) ++(0,1mm) rectangle ++(-1mm,-5mm);
    \draw (auxrechts) ++(0,1mm) rectangle ++(1mm,-5mm);
    
    \foreach\i in {-8,0,8}{%
        \draw[fill=white,opacity=1] (startpunkt1)++(-2mm,67mm)++(\i mm,0) rectangle ++(4mm,-33mm);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not much you can do imho apart from not using patterns and drawing the lines in other ways.  Patterns are special objects in a pdf and if the pdf viewer doesn't properly support them, tikz can not change that.

Comment: Perfect in `okular` and `evince`. The line width problem (and even the disappearing hatch) could be an antialiasing setting, try to zoom in and out. Yes, antialiasing is difficult. Yes, most viewers struggle with it, especially with subpixel lines.